# Import developed by Java project to Ionic project

Tags: android

Can I import a android project developed with java to  developed in Ironic? If you answer, I would be very happy.

Comment: Oh the irony that ionic faced with this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean Ionic (ironic is an unrelated word), I don't think so.  Ionic uses javascript, which is completely different from Java.  It's possible there are utilities that attempt to convert Java to Javascript, but given the differences in the languages, available libraries, etc. I would guess it would be just as easy to convert it by hand than to deal with whatever mess such a tool would spit out.

If you explain why you want to do this, possibly someone could offer an alternative that meets your needs.